# Uploading Directly to S3 vs Uploading Through EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services

Im developing a mobile app that will use AWS for its backend services. In the app I need to upload video files to S3 on a frequent basis, and I'm wondering what the recommended architecture would look like to make this scalable and efficient. Traffic could be high, and file sizes could be large.

-On one hand, I could upload directly to S3 using the S3 API on the client side. This would be the easiest option, but Im not sure of the negative implications associated with it.

-The other way to do it would be to go through an EC2 instance and handle the request using some PHP scripts and upload from there.

So my question is... **Are these two options equal, or are there major drawbacks to one of them opposed to another?** I will already have EC2 instances configured for database access if that makes any difference in how you approach the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend using "upload directly to S3 using the S3 API on the client side" as you can speed up the upload process by using AWS S3 part upload as your video files are going to large.

The second method will put extra CPU usage load on your EC2 instance as the script processing and upload to S3 will utilize CPU for the process.